# Do I need to use (int)$id before I use $id in bindValue in Php PDO

Tags: php, validation, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I just started using Php Data Objects and one thing I'm not sure about is do I have to validate that some variable is an integer before using it in the query. For example, like this:

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id']; // is this required    

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = ?");

$query->bindValue(1, $id);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: No it's not required (that's the beauty of prepared statements).

Comment: Ther very purpose of prepared statements, I'd say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not required for two reasons:

1. You're letting PDO know that you are going to query the database for a column ID. PDO isn't going to parse anything in `$_POST['id']`.
2. The second value of `bindValue` is automatically casted to a string (or of any type you might want to select). [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) `int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: Yeah so do I always have to use PDO::PARAM_STR? or specify the type of the variable?

Comment: It's the default optional argument for `bindValue`. So you don't need to specify.

Comment: So for example this query:

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE `name` = ? AND `id` = ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $_POST['name']);
    $query->bindValue(2, $_POST['id']);

    $query->execute();

So I don't need to specify that name is a string and id an integer?

Comment: Values that are bind won't be parsed and they are casted to a string.

Comment: So even id will be cast to string? if it is then I think there is a security hole

Comment: Yes. That's not a security but because `where id='1'` and `where id=1` returns the same results.

Comment: What if a user writes id="1 or 2=3"
This will return everything in the table.

Comment: You're binding the values, PDO won't parse anything in `$_POST`.